# How to merge two checked out branches of Subversion ( Offline Merge )?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, merge, offline

I am using Subversion with **rabbit-vcs** on Linux:

- Under merge it shows only the option to browse my branches on online `svn url`
- There is no option to give a offline svn folder as branch.

Since, I am pretty new to Subversion, so is it actually possible to merge 2 branches offline on svn ?

I have two branches already checked-out :

- `/home/user/branch1`
- `/home/user/trunk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [read this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html). Better yet, [read this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.advancedsyntax) as well. Arguably, understanding merging is the most important part of knowing how to use SVN correctly (for one, you'll think thousands of times before creating a new branch :) ).

Note that you merge two *committed sources* into a working copy. That is, even if you specify one of the sources as a working copy it *will still take its URL* for merge purposes. So this is sort of syntactic sugar that a client may or may not support. The reason for it is that the merge operation needs to identify the common ancestor of the sources and merge them change by change. That information is not present in a working copy.

Note a source for some possible confusion here: in many (most?) instances the working copy argument may specify *both* a source to be merged **and** the working copy to merge into).

Here's an example of what I mean: suppose you merge S1 and S2 into W. S1 and W contain file F. S2 does not. Now, there are at least two possibilities: (1) the common ancestor S of S1 and S2 contained the file and it was deleted in S2. Then merge should delete it from W; (2) S did not contain F and it was added in S1. Then F should remain in W. The information about S in simply not present locally, so the repository has to be contacted.

To find out exactly branch URLs your offline working copies come from run `svn info` in `branch1` and `trunk`.

Comment: What will be the `svn` command to merge the 2 branches (Without internet connection ?)

Comment: Sorry, got a little confused about what you meant by "offline". No, you can't do that (unless you mirror the repository locally). Edited my answer.

Comment: [ with svn repository on the cloud ]
But isn't that wired since we have all the info required for the merge offline available with us. Then why does it stops us from merging offline ?

Comment: I understand now.. that ok all the information is not available offline. Hm.. Then so we always need a internet connection  - Are you damm sure ?

Comment: What do you mean 'always'? Usually you can work offline and need to connect only for updates and commits. You usually merge after a commit, anyways, so at that point you need the connection anyway. It seems that you'd like to work on two branches at the same time for a while. That's a rather rare case. Consider Git or Mercurial. AFAIK with those tools you can do it.